Зачем настраивают передачу данных между VLAN'ами?
Зачем мы можем настраивать передачу данных между VLAN'ами? Ведь VLAN'ы зачастую создаются как раз чтобы логически распределить подключенные к одному коммутатору устройства по разным, никак не пересекающимся, сетям. Единственная польза такого подхода, которая мне приходит в голову - уменьшение широковещательных запросов, которые будут теперь бродить не по всей сети, а в пределах своей VLAN.
